# Select a portion of text from `wget` output and log to a file?

Tags: text-processing, logs, wget

I have this small script to test a FTP site:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O /dev/null ftp://someftpsite:password@ftp.test.com/testdump300 2>&1 | \
   grep '\([0-9.]\+ [M]B/s\)' >> wget300.log
```

And it shows output like this:

```
2018-07-26 22:30:06 (22.7 MB/s) - '/dev/null' saved [104857600]
```

Ok, and now I just want to have it like this:

```
2018-07-26 22:30:06 22.7
```

Anyone who can help? I suspect I should use `awk` or `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ wget -O /dev/null ftp://someftpsite:password@ftp.test.com/testdump300 2>&1 | \
   awk '/[0-9]+ [M]B\/s/{ sub("\\(",""); print $1,$2,$3 }' >> wget300.log
```

This will eliminate your need for `grep` as `awk` can also search for regex patterns.  It will remove the `(` before the speed and then print columns 1, 2, and 3. (date, time, and speed).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using `sed`:

```
$ wget -O /dev/null ftp://someftpsite:password@ftp.test.com/testdump300 2>&1 | \
   sed 's/(//;s/ [[:alpha:]]\+\/s.*$//' >> wget300.log
```

*How it works:*

- `s/(//;` - deletes the first parenthesis
- `s/ [[:alpha:]]\+\/s.*$//` - deletes everything starting from the <kbd>space</kbd> + 'MB/s' to the end `.*$`.

Another way using `perl`:

```
$ wget -O /dev/null ftp://someftpsite:password@ftp.test.com/testdump300 2>&1 | \
   perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if /^(.*)\s\((\S+)/' >> wget300.og
```

*How it works:*

- anything wrapped in parenthesis in Perl will be saved, hence the `$1` and `$2` variables. In this case we're matching everything up to but not including the <kbd>space</kbd> + parenthesis in `$1` and everything after the open parenthesis that's not a space `\S+` in the 2nd variable, `$2`.